# prevent client side form validation on form mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to prevent all validation rules from happening when a user saves a form as a draft.  My button is

```
<input id="saveDraft" type="button" value="Save As Draft" class="btn btn-default"/>
```

I have tried adding `novalidate` to it, as well as `formnovalidate` and `class="cancel"`

I just want the user to be able to save a draft without filling out all the required fields without any heavy javascript to remove all the validation attributes.

Edit:  .js file

```
        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        myDropzone.processQueue();          
        if (myDropzone.files.length == 0) {
            $('form').validate({
                onsubmit: false
            });
            $('form').submit();
        };
    });
```

Comment: Simply adding `class="cancel"` to the submit button will bypass the jQuery Validation plugin.  However, it's a moot point as the `type="button"` is ignored by the jQuery Validate plugin anyway.  The `.submit()` in your `click` handler is simply triggering the validation plugin by turning your button into a submit.  You also cannot call `.validate()` since the `unobtrusive-validation` plugin is already calling that method for you.  My recommendation would be to get rid of your `click` event listener entirely, change the button to `type="submit"` and try `class="cancel"` again.

Comment: BTW, the `novalidate` attribute is only for disabling HTML5 browser validation.

Comment: from what i understand, you are saying that the `<input type="button"` should be enough to prevent this form from validating, however, this is not what is happening, as the submit is being prevented by validation errors.

Comment: You are creating your own problem with your `click` handler.  You are taking a `type="button"` and forcing it to submit the form... which in turn activates validation.  Read my edited comment.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/p4bdevok/ OR http://jsfiddle.net/p4bdevok/1/

Comment: I do like your way better.  The issue with a submit button is, the form could ultimately save before the dropzone.js is finished uploading the files to the server, right?  That is why I am preventing the form from submitting while the `processQueue()` method runs.  Any ideas on other ways to handle this?

Comment: Not a whole lot of experience with DropZone.  The plugin is handling everything for you, so by manually trying to prevent the submit, you would potentially break the plugin.   Again, you cannot do anything with the `.validate()` method since you have `unobtrusive-validation` plugin.  However, you can still employ the same options via the plugin's `.setDefaults()` method.  `submitHandler` only fires when the form is valid and `invalidHandler` only fires when the form is invalid.  The exception is when you use `class="cancel"` in the `submit` button.

Answer (score 0):

You can tie into the onsubmit option and stop the validation. http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onsubmit

```
<input id="saveDraft" type="button" value="Save As Draft" class="btn btn-default"/>
<script type="text/javascript>
    $(input#saveDraft).click(function(event) {
        event.PreventDefault();
        $("form#myFormId").validate({
            onsubmit: false
        });
        $("form#myFormId").submit();
        //if you are submitting via ajax and want validation when the form is completed/submitted, set the 'onsubmit: true' before exiting this function.
    });
</script>
```

Keep in mind, any validation you are doing server-side will have to be dealt with as well.

Comment: already have a server side skip validation method in place.  going to try this, unfortunately I  have my "saveDraft" button tied into a bunch of dropzone.js stuff already

Comment: this is still not working for me.  see my edit for what i've tried

Comment: event.PreventDefault() has a syntax error. Should be event.preventDefault (lower-case 'p')